# reprepro Translation-en file issue

Tags: ubuntu, repository, package, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

I am using `reprepro` to create apt repository. However it is not creating Translation-en file (and neither the i18n directory). I've followed [this](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2006/09/setting_up_and_managing_an_apt_repository_with_reprepro/) and [this](http://davehall.com.au/blog/dave/2010/02/06/howto-setup-private-package-repository-reprepro-nginx) tutorial.

So when I do `apt-get update` on Ubuntu 12.04 server , I get warning:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://download.XXX.com/rep/dists/precise/contrib/i18n/Translation-en  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection [IP: A.B.C.D 80]
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be related to the repository at all. I had the same problem, and it went away as soon as I disabled apt-cacher. Your problem may be related to a proxy and not your repository, or it may be a combination of the two. Disabling the proxy for that site might help.